# Methods of javascript object running on jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have declared a Javascript class in this way:

```
function MyClass(params){

    this.setValues=function(params){
        this.myAttr1=params.attr1;
        this.myAttr2=params.attr2;
    }
    this.setValues(params);
}
```

As a result I have `MyClass` with public attributes `myAttr1`, `myAttr2` and a public function `setValues`.

When I do

```
var myObj=new MyClass({attr1:"hi",attr2:"ho"});
```

The object is created correctly. The problem comes when I want to send this object as a parameter in a jquery ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {id: "1", obj:myObj});
```

At this point I get an error because *params* in *setValues* is not defined. So this ajax call is trying to run `setValues()` (I don't now why).

I found a solution creating a function that return only the attributes inside `myClass`.

```
this.getValues=function(){
    return {myAttr1:this.myAttr1,myAttr2:this.myAttr2};
}
```

And then

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {id: "1", obj:myObj.getValues()});
```

But then any time I add an attribute I have to remember to return it in `getValues()`.
I guess there is a better solution. Maybe I am not following best practices on declaring a class.

Comment: you aren't passing `params` in when you call `setValues`. I'm not sure if that is the whole answer, but its definitely something. It would be better to not shadow the `params` argument that comes in with the class. So, I would remove `params` from your setValues signature.

Comment: sorry, I am, I forgot that when writing the question. edited. But the thing is, why is the function running in the ajax call?

Comment: If all you are doing is getting and setting some data points, just use an object literal instead of a function.

Comment: this is just a simple example for making easier to understand the point. But I really have a big class with many methods and attributes. Maybe I can't do what I am trying which is send my whole object as a part of a json. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.getValues` you should implement a `.toJSON` function to handle serializing your class to JSON. When your object is stringified (by an underlying call to JSON.stringify), it will automatically call `.toJSON`.